# Firebase pagination using a timestamp/date as the orderBy

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling to get pagination working when I use a date (firebase timestamp) to retrieve data.

This is basically what I do:

```
let jobsRef = db.collection("jobs")
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .limit(QUERY_LIMIT);
jobsRef = jobsRef.startAfter(this.props.jobs[this.props.jobs.length - 1].createdAt);
```

However it seems that i get returned items sometimes that I have just already received. I am guessing because of similar dates?
So how could I basically return a list of jobs ordered by createdAt and have an offset/limit (pagination)?

createdAt looks like the timestamp type: `23 October 2020 at 17:26:31 UTC+2`
When I log createdAt however I see this: `{seconds: 1603537477, nanoseconds: 411000000}`
Maybe I should be storing createdAt as a unix timestamp? Or what is the ideal way to deal with this?

Here is how it looks in the database (popup when i click edit on createdAt):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If multiple documents can have the same value for the field you're sorting on, passing in a value for that field is not guaranteed to point to a unique document. So you indeed may be passing in an ambiguous instruction, leading to an unwanted result.

When possible, I **highly** recommend passing the entire document to the Firestore API. This leaves it up to Firestore to take the necessary data from that document to uniquely/unambiguously find the anchor for your query.

So instead of:

```
jobsRef.startAfter(this.props.jobs[this.props.jobs.length - 1].createdAt);
```

Do:

```
jobsRef.startAfter(this.props.jobs[this.props.jobs.length - 1]);
```

Comment: The thing is this `this.props.jobs[this.props.jobs.length - 1]` returns not a firebase object but a standard js object of my job. I do this because i use NextJs and when i try return the firebase object in getInitialProps() then I get some Circular structure issue. (not sure how familiar you are with nextJs)

Comment: That is indeed a problem. I recommend keeping the `DocumentSnapshot` and passing that in. If that's not possible, try ordering on/and passing in the document ID as an extra condition, so that can be used to disambiguate between the documents.

Comment: Yeah doesnt seem to make a different and i cant find a solution to pass the document. I think i may just try Date.now() store the unix timestamp and that should be easy to paginate i hope

Comment: The Firestore `Timestamp` type is more accurate than a Unix millisecond timestamp, so that *should* not make it better. But it's hard to be sure, without seeing the actual data, how it's initialized, what it looks like in the database, and how it shows up in your query output,  in your question.

Comment: So when i use a createdAt that is a unix timestamp type format such as `1603558041210` then it works perfectly! I updated the question with an image how createdAt was before i changed it to a unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I was facings a similar problem, after may hours I finally found a solution, all you need to do is converting that number to firestore's Timestamp

```
import { Timestamp }. from @angular/fire/firestore;


let createdAt: number = 56772766688383;

let timestamp = Timestamp.fromMillis(createdAt);

//then pass that to startAfter

startAfter(timestamp)
```